# Select multiple associated objects in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am using Postgresql and my player model has some associations such as:

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end

class Substitution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end

class Penalty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

In my view I'm listing the lineup of a team, and behind each player's name I want to display the goals they scored, the penalties they received and the minute they were substituted (if any).

```
1. Player A - goal_icon (minute) goal_icon(minute) yellow_card_icon (minute) 
2. Player B - yellow_card_icon (minute) 
3. Player C - goal_icon (minute) substituted (minute)
```

So I obviously want to:

- Query all associations for one player at the same time
- Sort the query on the minute field

How do I do this?

Comment: You cannot "query all associations for one player" at once because they are different entities, and do not share the same interface (as polymorphic associations for example). There are several minute fields, which one do you want to sort on?

Comment: Ok, that confirms my initial thoughts. So how would I approach this? Write a method that collects all goals, subs and penalties and store them in an array with the minute as index (to sort on)? -- when I type it I already see a performance bottleneck, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) or [Multiple Table Inheritance](https://github.com/peterhamilton/citier/) and then be able to call: `@player.events.sort(:minute)`.

For example with STI:

```
class Player < AR
  has_many :events
end

class Event < AR
  belongs_to :player
end

class Goal < Event end
class Substitution < Event end
class Penalty < Event end

@player.events.sort(:minute) # [#Goal, #Goal, #Penalty]
```

Comment: I have considered it, but how do I implement the extra attributes each of these events has? For instance, "Goal" needs an "own_goal" attribute -- and "Penalty" has a boolean "red" to determine if a red card was given.

Comment: Well in STI you would have one big non-relationalized tables with the closure of attributes of all classes. In MTI each table would have it's own specific columns.